# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 1

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on android application. I want to get specific index of id , but it returns always first no of index id or application crashes .please help me how to solve error. Thanks

here is my code:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        HttpService httpService = new HttpService("http://192.168.0.103/GetActiveGroupMember.php");
        try
        {
            httpService.ExecutePostRequest();

            if(httpService.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                result = httpService.getResponse();
                ArrayList<Integer> m_idlist = null;

                listid = new ArrayList<>();
                listid.add(result);
               // System.out.println("ListID...  "+listid+" ListId Size "+listid.size());
                System.out.println("ListID...  "+listid+" ListId Size "+listid.size());
             //   Log.d("Result", result);
                System.out.println("Result "+result);
                if(result != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                        JSONObject object;
                        JSONArray array;

                        member m;
                        members = new ArrayList<member>();

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            m= new member();
                            object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                          //  m.username = object.getString("username");
                            m.id = object.getInt("id");

                            members.add(m);

                            int m_id  = m.id;
                            System.out.println("mem_id  = "+m_id);

                            m_idlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            m_idlist.add(i);

                          System.out.println("five no id = "+m_idlist.get(i)); // TO print all Id

                        }
                         if(m_idlist.size()>5){
                            System.out.println("five no id = "+m_idlist.get(5));
                           }
                     //   System.out.println("Total member  = "+members.size());

                    }
```

Error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 1
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
W/System.err:     at com.example.moraya.adminmodule.GetActiveGroupMemberACtivity$GetHttpResponse.doInBackground(GetActiveGroupMemberACtivity.java:121)
W/System.err:     at com.example.moraya.adminmodule.GetActiveGroupMemberACtivity$GetHttpResponse.doInBackground(GetActiveGroupMemberACtivity.java:56)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your list only contains **one** item, so there is no item with index 5.

Comment: System.out.println("five no id = "+m_idlist.get(5)); you're pushing the system at index 5 when it only have 1 item in list

Comment: `m_idlist.get(5)` if your list is not having 6 elements in total than it will always throw this error. Add a check for list size and put this code in that condition.

Comment: what is the value of listid.size() & m_idlist.size()?

Comment: Agreed with everybody else, you need to have a check statement ( a simple if statement ) to check if the element exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("five no id = "+m_idlist.get(5));
```

You probably have no element in the list with index 5, add a if statement to check your index with the size of the list.

In your case:

```
if (5 < m_idlist.size()) { ... }
```

Comment: k.sir, Actually I have 10 id in int m_id  = m.id; and i am adding m_id  into Arraylistlist as m_idlist.add(m_id); and after that I am getting the id  of 5th no position by using  System.out.println("five no id = "+m_idlist.get(5));  Then it returns 1st no of position id..please help me .

Comment: No, it is said that there is only 1 element `Invalid index 5, size is 1`

Comment: Then what are the println's printing as @bhaumiksoni asked?

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare this line  `m_idlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();` above of for loop

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Great Answer...You saved my time.